# Number of records per day without timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to query the number of quotes we receive per day compared to last 14 days.

The first query I tried was:

```
SELECT CreatedDateTime, count(CreatedDateTime)
FROM dbo.Quotes
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 14,0)
GROUP BY CreatedDateTime
ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC
```

However I think the timestamp on the data counts each record individually rather than groups the records per day.  How can I amend this query?

I tried the below but it comes back with an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
SELECT convert(char(10), dbo.Quotes.CreatedDateTime, count (CreatedDateTime)
FROM dbo.Quotes
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 14,0)
GROUP BY convert(char(10), dbo.Quotes.CreatedDateTime
ORDER BY CreatedDateTime DESC
```

Comment: You're missing the format from convert, for example "CreatedDateTime, 112), count" or you could use Convert(date,  CreatedDateTime)

Comment: `GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the same column that you are using for the `GROUP BY`.
Naturally, there will be only one value on each group.
try to use `COUNT(*)` instead.
Also, to ignore the time part the simplest thing to do is cast to date (assuming your database version is 2008 or higher)

```
SELECT CAST(CreatedDateTime as Date), count(*)
FROM dbo.Quotes
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 14,0)
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDateTime as Date)
ORDER BY CAST(CreatedDateTime as Date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you are grouping by date and time and you would need to group by time only.

Just modify the group clause to this

```
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDateTime , '%Y-%m-%d')
```

so your query would look like

```
SELECT CreatedDateTime, count(*) as totalQuotes
FROM dbo.Quotes
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 14,0)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDateTime , '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(CreatedDateTime , '%Y-%m-%d') DESC
```

Comment: Yes, right .. just saw it was mentioned in the tags. I did it as per mysql